# Mono<List<T>> difference with Flux<T> in Spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

My understand is `Mono<List<T>>` is a synchronized `Flux<T>` 
and Flux could not be a rest api response.

Am I right?

If not, what's the different between `Mono<List<T>>` and `Flux<T>`
or could a Flux could be a rest api response in some where ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- as a return type, `Mono<List<T>>` means that you'll get asynchronously a full list of `T` elements in one shot.
- `Flux<T>` means that you'll get zero to many `T` elements, possibly one by one as they come.

If you're getting such return types from an HTTP client such as `WebClient`, `Mono<List<T>>` and `Flux<T>` might be more or less equivalent from a runtime perspective, if the returned `Content-Type` is for example `"application/json"`. In this case, the decoder will deserialize the response in one shot. The only different is, `Flux<T>` provides more interesting operators and you can always `collectList` and fall back to a `Mono<List>`.

On the other hand, if the returned `Content-Type` is a streaming one, for example `"application/stream+json"` then this definitely has an impact as you'll get the elements one by one as they come. In fact, if the returned stream is infinite, choosing `Flux<T>` is very important as the other one will never complete.

Answer (score 2):

- `Mono<List<T>>` will emit zero or maximal one list of item of type `T`.
- `Flux<T>`will emit zero or many items of type `T`

`Momo` wraps is bounded and `Flux` is not.

> `Mono<List<T>>` is a synchronized Flux

Mono and Flux are both a [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) implementation of a Publisher interface specified in a [Reactive Stream Specification](http://www.reactive-streams.org/).

Reactor Mono class:

`public abstract class Mono<T> implements Publisher<T> {...}`

Reactor Mono class:

`public abstract class Flux<T> implements Publisher<T> {...}`

> Flux could not be a rest api response.
>   Of course `Flux`can be used as response type of REST API. By using Flux as return type you can easily switch from asynchronous to synchronous processing . If you use Spring Boot you can even stream data to your consumer just by changing the `Content-Type` of you API endpoint to `application/stream+json` as mention by @Brian.

Note that Flux and Mono are non blocking which means that you working threads (computer resources) can be used more efficiently.

Comment: How to convert `Mono<List<T>>` to `Flux<T>`?

Comment: How about this: ```mono.map(list -> list.toArray(new T[0]))
                .flux()
                .flatMap(Flux::just);```